# Kafka broker fails to start in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a pretty standard compose file. When I run it first time all containers run good. When I run `docker-compose -f kafka-compose.yml down` and run it again I get the following error:

`broker             | [2021-10-06 09:57:13,398] ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/1, node already exists and owner '72075955082625025' does not match current session '72075962265632769' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral)`

I didn't find `server.properties` in broker container. May it be the reason? What must be changed?

As I read that may be caused by the fact that not all settings are persisted in mounted folders hence it reloads on start. But which one?

Here's my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'


networks:
  default-dev-network:
    external: true

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes: 
      - $PWD/kafka-data/zookeeper/var-lib/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - $PWD/kafka-data/zookeeper/var-lib/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
      - $PWD/kafka-data/zookeeper/etc-kafka:/etc/kafka
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - default-dev-network

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/kafka-data/kafka/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - $PWD/kafka-data/kafka-home:/etc/kafka

    # entrypoint: sh -c 'sleep 30 && /etc/confluent/docker/run'

    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,\
org.apache.kafka=ERROR,\
kafka=ERROR,\
kafka.cluster=ERROR,\
kafka.controller=ERROR,\
kafka.coordinator=ERROR,\
kafka.log=ERROR,\
kafka.server=ERROR,\
kafka.zookeeper=ERROR,\
state.change.logger=ERROR"
      # KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=ERROR, kafka.coordinator=ERROR, state.change.logger=ERROR"
      KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
      KAFKA_TOOLS_LOG4J_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
    networks:
      - default-dev-network

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
    networks:
      - default-dev-network

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.2.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - default-dev-network
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this error is common if you aren't deleting your volume data across container restarts

> didn't find server.properties in broker container

It's there...

```
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
sh-4.4$ ls /etc/kafka/
connect-console-sink.properties    connect-mirror-maker.properties  secrets
connect-console-source.properties  connect-standalone.properties    server.properties
connect-distributed.properties     consumer.properties          tools-log4j.properties
connect-file-sink.properties       kraft                trogdor.conf
connect-file-source.properties     log4j.properties         zookeeper.properties
connect-log4j.properties       producer.properties
sh-4.4$ ls /etc/kafka/server.properties
/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

> not all settings are persisted in mounted folders hence it reloads on start. But which one?

They are, but the error you're getting is from the Zookeeper mount, not Kafka's volume data

Comment: Is there some common practice how to clean volumes except doing it manually?

Comment: Since they are just host directories, then no.

Comment: So it means that I can't persist kafka data. If I don't mount directories kafka will clean it after container recreation. Right?

Comment: I've been able to mount volumes for Kafka containers before, but I don't recall if it was the Confluent images. But yes, they'll be ephemeral

Answer (score 0):

## identify which volumes to remove

```
docker volume ls
```

## remove them

```
docker volume rm beepboop_zookeeper_data
docker volume rm beepboop_zookeeper_txns
```

## restart kafka

```
docker-compose restart kafka
```